# how can i print A & B in echo message within Ant script

Tags: ant

```
<target name="three">
<echo message="A & B"/>
</target>
```

whenever i m running this code it shows the error like `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.`
how can i print A & B
pls help me out guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`

Answer (score 7):

Ant scripts must be valid XML, so the ampersand needs XML-escaping:

```
<target name="three">
<echo message="A &amp; B"/>
</target>
```